# How can i apply remove alphabet function on active sheet loop?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Function StripChar(Txt As String) As String
With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
.Global = True
.Pattern = "\D"
StripChar = .Replace(Txt, "")
End With
End Function
```

So i am trying to apply this function on bottom range via loop through cells

```
Sub Alphabetremove()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Lastrow As Integer
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("F2:F" & Lastrow).Select
    With Selection
    .Value = StripChar(.Value)
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: you will need to loop and run each value through the function one at a time.

Comment: You might benefit from reading 
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you cannot run the function `.Value = StripChar(.Value)` on a range at once (as you tried) but only on a single cell. Therfore you need to loop from row `2` to `LastRow` and apply the function to each single cell.

Also note that row counting variables need to be of type `Long` because Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle. Actually I recommend [always to use `Long` instead of `Integer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long/26409520#26409520) as there is no benefit in using `Integer` in VBA.

Also if you set your worksheet to a variable `ws` you need to use this variable for **all** `.Cells` and `.Range` objects otherwise this is useless.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Alphabetremove()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet 'better define a workseet by name unless you use the code for multiple worksheets: 
                         'Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MySheet")

    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In ws.Range("F2:F" & LastRow)
        Cell.Value = StripChar(Cell.Value)
    Next Cell
End Sub
```

Finally I highly recommend you to read [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) and apply this to all of your code.